# strange results when trying to center a 1000px wide container

Tags: html, css

I have a problem where I'm trying to have a layout where some elements like my horizontal nav bar are meant to have a band of colour across the page where as others are meant to just be 1000px wide in the middle of the screen

So I have the html and css which I believe should work just fine and indeed it does until I load the page up in my android phone at which point the bar that's meant to stretch across the page seems to leave a gap on the right hand side and I can't figure out what the problem is.

Can anyone enlighten me?

Live version http://belfastwebdeveloper.com/

code:

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="logo" class="widthContainer"><a href="/thimamai/pages/home"><img src="/thimamai/img/logo.png" alt="" /></a></div>
</div>
<div id="navBar">
    <div class="widthContainer">
        <a href="/thimamai/pages/home">Home</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a href="/thimamai/users/logout">Logout</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a href="/thimamai/users/dashboard">Dashboard</a>                               
    </div>
</div>
<div  class="widthContainer">
    <div id="content">
          inside content div          
    </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
    <div class="fontSize12">&copy; JDL - 1880 - 2014</div>
</div>
```

Styles:

```
    /** * Eric Meyer's Reset CSS v2.0 (http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) * http://cssreset.com */html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,b, u, i, center,dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,fieldset, form, label, legend,table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,time, mark, audio, video {    margin: 0;  padding: 0; border: 0;  font-size: 100%;    font: inherit;  vertical-align: baseline;}/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {    display: block;}body {  line-height: 1;}ol, ul {    list-style: none;}blockquote, q {   quotes: none;}blockquote:before, blockquote:after,q:before, q:after {   content: '';    content: none;}table {  border-collapse: collapse;  border-spacing: 0;}

#header, #footer{text-align:center;}
#content{padding:20px;}
#navBar{background:#4750a2;line-height:30px;}
#navBar a {color:#ffffff; text-decoration:none;}
.widthContainer{width:1000px;margin:auto;}
```

Comment: From what you have said, it looks like your *inner* css is being applied to the *outer* wrapper. Wouldn't you want it to be: `.widthContainer { width:100%; background-color:someColour; }` and `.content { width:1000px; margin:0 auto; }`

Comment: I think it is as I meant it. The #content div is supposed to be inside the .widthcontainer. So .header should stretch the entire width and then inside .widthcontainer makes sure that everything is inside 1000px wide div so it's on screen. - If you can check it on andriod it will make more sense I think.

Answer (score 0):

It appears your wrapper system changes between `#navBar` and `#content`:

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="logo" class="widthContainer"><a href="/thimamai/pages/home"><img src="/thimamai/img/logo.png" alt="" /></a></div>
</div>
<div id="navBar">                     <!-- WRAPPER -->
    <div class="widthContainer">  <!-- INNER CONTAINER -->
        <a href="#">Home</a>
        <a href="#">Logout</a>
        <a href="#">Dashboard</a>                               
    </div>
</div>
<div  class="widthContainer">          <!-- WRAPPER -->
    <div id="content">             <!-- INNER CONTAINER -->
          inside content div          
    </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
    <div class="fontSize12">&copy; JDL - 1880 - 2014</div>
</div>
```

Here you are treating the `.widthContainer` as the wrapper in the first instance, then the child in the next.

If you flip your `#content` and `.widthcontainer` divs, it should help.